# Validate cypher query in Frontend

Tags: reactjs, neo4j, cypher

I am working on a simple app.
I am using neo4j db and in the frontend I have given an option to the users to write a cypher query that would then be executed in neo4j and would give expected response
I wanted to know if there is any library or any way apart from regex where I can check for the syntax in the frontend only without having to run it in the neo4j.

Comment: You can send the query with EXPLAIN in front and catch any errors. Also check neo4j browser and neodash on github to get further ideas.

Answer (score 2):

At least for OpenCypher the syntax is specified and published: https://opencypher.org/resources/
You could use these specifications and general syntax checker tools and verify it on the frontend yourself.
Though you should know that Neo4j's current Cypher is an extension of OpenCypher, and other implementations of OpenCypher like Memgraph's aren't 100% compatible. So while this check allows general compliance with OpenCypher, it can't handle non-standardized features and extensions.

Comment: What are the general syntax checking tools?

Comment: E.g. https://github.com/tunnelvisionlabs/antlr4ts (typescript based, but apparently backend only ?), and general tutorial see https://tomassetti.me/parsing-in-javascript/ .